# Scraping Multi level data using Scrapy, optimum way

Tags: python, selenium, data-structures, web-crawler, scrapy

I have been wondering what would be the best way to scrap the multi level of data using scrapy
I will describe the situation in four stage,

1. current architecture that i am following to scrape this data
2. basic code structure
3. the difficulties and why i think there has to be a better option
4. The format in which i have tried to store the data and failed and then succeeded partially

**Current Architecture**

1. the data structure

> First page : List of Artist
>
> Second page : List of Album for each Artist
>
> Third Page : list of Songs for each Album

2. basic code structure

class MusicLibrary(Spider):
    name = 'MusicLibrary'

```
def parse(self, response):

    items = Discography()
    items['artists'] = []
    for artist in artists:
            item = Artist()
            item['albums'] = []
            item['artist_name'] = "name"
            items['artists'].append(item)
            album_page_url = "extract link to album and yield that page"
            yield Request(album_page_url,
                          callback=self.parse_album,
                          meta={'item': items,
                                'artist_name': item['artist_name']})

def parse_album(self, response):
    base_item = response.meta['item']
    artist_name = response.meta['artist_name']
    # this will search for the artist added in previous method and append album under that artist
    artist_index = self.get_artist_index(base_item['artists'], artist_name)
    albums = "some path selector"
    for album in albums:
        item = Album()
        item['songs'] = []
        item['album_name'] = "name"
        base_item['artists'][artist_index]['albums'].append(item)
        song_page_url = "extract link to song and yield that page"
        yield Request(song_page_url,
                      callback=self.parse_song_name,
                      meta={'item':  base_item,
                            "key": item['album_name'],
                            'artist_index': artist_index})

def parse_song_name(self, response):
    base_item = response.meta['item']
    album_name = response.meta['key']
    artist_index = response.meta["artist_index"]
    album_index = self.search(base_item['artists'][artist_index]['albums'], album_name)
    songs = "some path selector "

    for song in songs:
        item = Song()
        song_name = "song name"
        base_item['artists'][artist_index]['albums'][album_index]['songs'].append(item)
        # total_count (total songs to parse) = Main Artist page is having the list of total songs for each artist
        # current_count(currently parsed) = i will go to each artist->album->songs->[] and count the length

        # i will yield the base_item only when songs to scrape and song scraped count matches
        if current_count == total_count:
            yield base_item
```

3. the difficulties and why i think there has to be a better option

   - currently i am yielding item object only when all the pages and sub-pages are scraped with condition that the songs to scrape and song scraped count matches..
   - but give the nature of scraping and volume of scraping ...there are some pages which are to give me code other than (200-status ok) and those songs will not be scraped and item count will not match
   - so at the end, when  even though 90% pages will be scraped successfully and  count will not match nothing will be yielded and all CPU power will be lost..
4. The format in which i have tried to store the data and failed and then succeeded partially

   - i wanted the data for each item object in single line format
     i.e. artistName-Albumname-song name
     so if artist A has 1 album (aa) with 8 song ... 8 items will be stores with one entry(item) per song
   - but with the current format when i have tried yielding every time in last function "parse_song_name" it was yielding that complex structure every time and object was incremental every time...
   - then i thought the appending everything in first Discography->artist then Artist->albums and then Albums->songs was the problem but when i have removed appending and tried without that i was only yielding one object which is the last one not all..
   - so finally , developed this work around as described before but it does not work every time ( in case of no 200 status code)
   - and when it work , after yielding , i have written a pipline where i parse this jSON again and store it in the data format i initially wanted ( one line for each song --flat structure)

can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong here or how can i make this more efficient and make work when some of the pages return non 200 code?

Comment: could you please post the start-url ?

Comment: if possible please post the output json format also?
If you could post the start-url that will be great , because sometimes some simple tweaking of the url can reduce extra lines of codes as well as requests too.

Comment: i have started afresh from the failed version of my code where all the item objects were having same album and artist name but different song name ...the problem there was mutable object.. item list/dictionary is mutable object and every callback method was receiving that same object and all th iterations were changing same object....

Comment: so here the solution for me , was to use copy.deepcopy to create new item object in each callback function and yield that new object instead , leaving that base reference as it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code above was:

1. **Mutable object** ( list, dict) : and all the callbacks were changing that same object in each loop hence ...first and second level of data was being overwritten in last third loop ( mp3_son_url) ...(this was my failed attempt)

the solution was to use simple **copy.deepcopy** and create a new object from response.meta object in callback method and not change the base_item object

will try to explain the full answer when i get some time..

Comment: I should probably not hold my breath for the explanation :)

Comment: I hold my breath far too long, not any more! not any more!

Comment: Hi this was lost in the past, problem here was when you pass your item object to meta, it is being passed by refrence rather than value
so inside every for loop and  between callback, the same item object was passed ( pass by reference) and hence unpredictable results, solution is to create a new copy of the object, modify and pass along the callbacks